# Will Allah create again after the Day of Judgement and what did he create before mankind?

Tags: quran, hadith, allah, creation, day-of-judgement

In Surah Ankabut (29:19), it is said

> See they not how Allah originates the creation, the repeats it. Verily, that is easy for Allah.

At first, I wondered if this means that he will create the like of mankind again after the Day of Judgement, but I doubted this personal interpretation after reading then next verse which says

> ... originated the creation and then Allah will bring forth the creation of the Hereafter.

So I'm guessing that the "repeats" part is in reference to resurrection, not new beings.

In any case, I am wondering if there is any evidence in the Qur'an or Hadith for Allah creating once again after the Day of Judgement. Similarly, do we know whether there there creations (other than angels) before humans?

Comment: Hereafter is a creation but not the same as the creation of this world, this unicerse. Only Allah is uncreated.

Comment: @MoziburUllah that does not answer my question. And for whoever downvoted the question, kindly explain your reason for it as the question is quite reasonable as far as I can tell.

Comment: If you haven't noticed It wasn't an answer. However, it is correct. Moreover, despite your protestations, it does answer your question which shows a deep lack of understanding of the Qu'ran - but why is this surprising from someone who calls himself Faust? You do know the story of Faust, the guy who sold his soul to Satan?

Comment: @MoziburUllah I chose the name because the Creator was merciful to Faust in the end, exemplifying that he may choose to redeem anyone. Instead of being condescending, perhaps you can respond with a full answer. If it makes sense, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: It's a strange choice because Faust is a byword in the language for the bargain he made with Mephistopheles, the one I referred to above - selling his soul to Satan. I'm not being condescending and nor am I interested in writing an answer as in my opinion, the question shows a poor understanding of the Qu'ran and Islamic theology, despite the quotes, because as the phrase goes - the devil can quote scripture for his own purposes.

Comment: @MoziburUllah That's a very unhelpful approach imo. The OP might not have a good graps of neither the Quran nor the Islamic theology, and that's why he's asking a question. His nickname has got nothing to do with the question. He asked it in a quite respectful manner.

Comment: @SpiderRico: He's not making any sense. First he says "that does not answer the question", and then he says he "would be happy to accept [a full answer]". That's just bizarre.